# Docker ContainerID Unavailable

Tags: docker, docker-machine, docker-registry

Its being several times that my containers restart automatically with following error.The container is running along with chef on an ec2 instance. Here is the logs says

```
time="2016-10-19T23:23:36.382529790Z" level=info msg="GET /v1.16/containers/container1/json"
time="2016-10-19T23:23:36.382715521Z" level=error msg="Handler for GET /v1.16/containers/container1/json returned error: no such id: container1"
time="2016-10-19T23:23:36.382746955Z" level=error msg="HTTP Error" err="no such id: container1" statusCode=404
time="2016-10-19T23:23:36.383675061Z" level=info msg="GET /v1.16/containers/container1/json"
time="2016-10-19T23:23:36.383781507Z" level=error msg="Handler for GET /v1.16/containers/container1/json returned error: no such id: container1"
time="2016-10-19T23:23:36.383807920Z" level=error msg="HTTP Error" err="no such id: container1" statusCode=404
time="2016-10-19T23:23:36.384686602Z" level=info msg="GET /v1.16/containers/container1/json"
```

**> Docker Version**

```
docker version
Client:
 Version:      1.9.1
 API version:  1.21
 Go version:   go1.4.2
 Git commit:   a34a1d5/1.9.1
 Built:
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.9.1
 API version:  1.21
 Go version:   go1.4.2
 Git commit:   a34a1d5/1.9.1
 Built:
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

**> Docker Info**

```
docker info
Containers: 1
Images: 50
Server Version: 1.9.1
Storage Driver: devicemapper
 Pool Name: docker-202:1-263798-pool
 Pool Blocksize: 65.54 kB
 Base Device Size: 107.4 GB
 Backing Filesystem:
 Data file: /dev/loop0
 Metadata file: /dev/loop1
 Data Space Used: 5.981 GB
 Data Space Total: 107.4 GB
 Data Space Available: 40.37 GB
 Metadata Space Used: 4.989 MB
 Metadata Space Total: 2.147 GB
 Metadata Space Available: 2.142 GB
 Udev Sync Supported: true
 Deferred Removal Enabled: false
 Deferred Deletion Enabled: false
 Deferred Deleted Device Count: 0
 Data loop file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/data
 Metadata loop file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/metadata
 Library Version: 1.02.93-RHEL7 (2015-01-28)
Execution Driver: native-0.2
Logging Driver: json-file
Kernel Version: 4.1.13-19.30.amzn1.x86_64
Operating System: Amazon Linux AMI 2015.09
CPUs: 1
Total Memory: 3.679 GiB
Name: container1
ID: ARKR:MFOG:UO6J:LRZS:336R:TNTE:QTIA:64GD:B6HD:CRU6:G2YE:AWLZ
Username: test
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
WARNING: bridge-nf-call-iptables is disabled
WARNING: bridge-nf-call-ip6tables is disabled
```

Here is the logs from the /var/log/messages file

```
Oct 19 10:15:04 ip-10-2-130-44 kernel: [14529077.356962] veth98ee000: renamed from eth0
Oct 19 10:15:04 ip-10-2-130-44 kernel: [14529077.368372] docker0: port 1(veth85fc3ec) entered disabled state
Oct 19 10:15:04 ip-10-2-130-44 kernel: [14529077.400306] docker0: port 1(veth85fc3ec) entered disabled state
Oct 19 10:15:04 ip-10-2-130-44 kernel: [14529077.411398] device veth85fc3ec left promiscuous mode
Oct 19 10:15:04 ip-10-2-130-44 kernel: [14529077.413684] docker0: port 1(veth85fc3ec) entered disabled state
Oct 19 10:15:04 ip-10-2-130-44 kernel: [14529077.491597] XFS (dm-1): Unmounting Filesystem
Oct 19 10:15:07 ip-10-2-130-44 ntpd[3332]: Deleting interface #972 veth85fc3ec, fe80::1cd7:99ff:fe84:1495#123, interface stats: received=0, sent=0, droppedd
=0, active_time=29844 secs
Oct 19 10:15:16 ip-10-2-130-44 kernel: [14529088.927071] XFS (dm-1): Mounting V4 Filesystem
Oct 19 10:15:16 ip-10-2-130-44 kernel: [14529088.935124] XFS (dm-1): Ending clean mount
```

Have anybody encountered this error before, please let me know if any additional information required.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this exact error and it occurs whenever this an issue with JSON configuration for container. For my case, there was a typo in add-host entries where I added an extra colon, example 'a::b' instead of 'a:b'. It took me an hour to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I could able to reproduce this error. If you query a container that doesn't exist on the docker host then it will give you statusCode=404 error.

`# curl <dockerMachineIP>:2376/v1.21/containers/<validContainerName>/json` will give you all the details about the container.

The same will through you error **statusCode=404** if you curl with an invalid container id.